# Custom Javascript and css added to Wordpress, however, still not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

- The content of the site that I am currently developing centers around an ancient Tibetan scripture. My goal is to provide the user with a basic interactive translation of the text. Most important is for the user to be able to experience the text in both the English and Tibetan languages. I decided to utilize a simple highlighting scheme to show how the English word/phrase is derived from the Tibetan script and vice versa. When hovering over a particular word/phrase both the Tibetan script and English equivalent are highlighted.
- This is accomplished by adding a **span** around every word/phrase and linking the two by putting each word/phrase in the other language's **title** attribute.
- For starters, I have this on JSFiddle for reference [JSFiddle Mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/6BH27/1/).

I created highlight.js and added it to the /assets/js folder of my Wordpress Theme using the following:

```
$('span[title]').hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    $('span:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').addClass('highlight');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    $('span:contains("'+$(this).attr('title')+'")').removeClass('highlight');
}
);
```

I then added the following to the Custom.css file of my wordpress theme:

```
 span {
}
.highlight {
     background:yellow;
}
```

I then added the following to the "mthemes_enqueue_scripts()" function of my functions.php file.

```
wp_register_script( 'highlight',        get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/highlight.js' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'highlight' );
```

- Here is a link to the page [Page with Javascript](http://illuminationofthetruethought.com/the-offering-of-praise-and-a-pledge-to-compose-the-work/)
- The Javascript is not functional. I've used a couple of tools to try and validate that the css is being loaded from my Custom.css file, and it is. Using View Source I've been able to confirm that the highlight.js is being loaded along with my other JS.
- Any help remedying this problem is GREATLY appreciated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('span[title]').hover(
function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
    jQuery('span:contains("'+jQuery(this).attr('title')+'")').addClass('highlight');
},
function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
    jQuery('span:contains("'+jQuery(this).attr('title')+'")').removeClass('highlight');
}
);
```

Comment: I replaced all instances of $ with 'jQuery' and also moved jquery.highlight.js to /assets/js/jquery

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help in correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading jQuery after the custom js file. The highlight.js seems to be written in jQuery so maybe load it in the footer instead.

Comment: If you look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script You'll see the option to add the file to the footer instead of the header.

Comment: I changed the $in_footer parameter to 'True'                                                                                                                      **wp_register_script( 'highlight',        get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery/jquery.highlight.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );**

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help in correcting my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Your page raise a javascript error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

In wordpress you must use 'jQuery' instead of '$' to call jquery functions. So replace all instances of '$' by 'jQuery' in highlight.js.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help in correcting my mistake!